# ¿Cómo programar un CheckboxColumn dentro de un GridView en Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

Soy principiante en Yii 2, y lo que necesito es programar los CheckboxColumn de manera que con cada Checkbox seleccionado como deseleccionado en un GridView, inserten un nuevo dato en otra tabla.

Esta esta es la estructura de la vista que tengo, llamada `ingresoasistencia.php`:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\grid\CheckboxColumn;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\Planificacion */

$this->title = 'Ingresar Asistencias'
?>
<div class="planificacion-view">

    <h2><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h2>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'nombreSesion',
            'fecha',
            'objetivosPlanificacion:ntext',
        ],
    ]) ?>
    <br />
    <h2><?= 'Alumnos del Taller' ?></h2>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'rutAlumno',
            'nombreAlumno',
            'apellidoAlumno',
            'cursoAlumno',
            ['class' => CheckboxColumn::className(),
            'header' => 'Asistencia',
            ],

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Este es parte del controlador que uso, llamado `PlanificacionController.php`

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\Planificacion;
use common\models\PlanificacionSearch;
use common\models\AlumnoSearch;
use common\models\Alumno;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

class PlanificacionController extends Controller{

//Otras funciones

public function actionIngresoasistencia($id)
    {
        $searchModel = new AlumnoSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('ingresoasistencia', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Planificacion::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Y el modelo al que deseo insertar datos en la base de datos es este, llamado `Asistencia.php`

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "asistencia".
 *
 * @property integer $idAsistencia
 * @property integer $idPlanificacion
 * @property string $rutAlumno
 * @property string $asistencia
 *
 * @property Planificacion $idPlanificacion0
 * @property Alumno $rutAlumno0
 */
class Asistencia extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'asistencia';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['idPlanificacion'], 'required'],
            [['idPlanificacion'], 'integer'],
            [['rutAlumno', 'asistencia'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['idPlanificacion'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Planificacion::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['idPlanificacion' => 'idPlanificacion']],
            [['rutAlumno'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Alumno::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['rutAlumno' => 'rutAlumno']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'idAsistencia' => 'Id Asistencia',
            'idPlanificacion' => 'Nombre Sesión',
            'rutAlumno' => 'Nombre Alumno',
            'asistencia' => 'Asistencia',
            'rutAlumno2' => 'Apellido Alumno'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getIdPlanificacion0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Planificacion::className(), ['idPlanificacion' => 'idPlanificacion']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getRutAlumno0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Alumno::className(), ['rutAlumno' => 'rutAlumno']);
    }

}
```

La cosa es que haya un botón que que al presionarlo, haga esto con cada Checkbox (en pseudocodigo):

```
Si Checkbox está seleccionado {

Insertar en Asistencia valores (rutAlumno de la fila en el GridView, idPlanificación que se encuentra en $model de la vista, asistencia = '1')

} Si Checkbox esta deseleccionado {

Insertar en Asistencia valores (rutAlumno de la fila en el GridView, idPlanificación que se encuentra en $model de la vista, asistencia = '0')

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar por favor.

Comment: Saludos amigo, pudiste solucionar ? tengo un problema muy similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he solucionado asi

Creo una vista del modelo de asistentes con un kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['asistencia'],'post');?>
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id_asis',
        [
            'attribute' => 'apellidos',
            'value' => 'apellidos',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'nombres',
            'value' => 'nombres',
        ],
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            'rowSelectedClass' => GridView::TYPE_INFO,
            'name'=>'seleccion[]',
        ]
    ],
]);
?>
<?= Html::submitButton('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span> Guardar Asistencia', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg']) ?>
<?= Html::endForm();?>
```

en mi controller tengo la acción asistencia

```
    public function actionAsistencia() {
    $searchModel = new AsistentesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $selection = (array) Yii::$app->request->post('seleccion'); //typecasting
    foreach ($selection as $id) {
        $model = new Asistencia();
        $model->id_asis=$id;
        $model->reunion=117; //id de reunion a la que asistira
                             //esto deberia tomarse como parámetro
        $model->asistio=1; //1 true 0 false
        $model->save();
    }
    return $this->render('asistencia', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.
saludos.
Me he guiado en las respuestas de este post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893566/how-can-i-get-the-selected-data-item-rows-in-checkboxcolumn-gridview-yii2/46510172#46510172